# Android AsyncTask not being called in for loop

Tags: java, android, image, server, download

I'm working in a project and I need to download files from a folder in a server. I have this code here to download a imagem from the web.

```
    public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

    private String requestUrl, imagename_;
    private Bitmap bitmap ;
    private FileOutputStream fos;

    protected GetImages(String requestUrl, String _imagename_) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.imagename_ = _imagename_ ;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl+ imagename_);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        if(!ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename_))
        {
            ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
        }
    }
}
```

And to download a single image I invoce the AsyncTask like this:

```
new GetImages(getString(R.string.link), "1.jpg").execute();
```

And it works fine. The problem is that I want to download more images so I have something like this:

```
public void AdicionarImagem_Pasta() {

    for (int i : arrayID) {
        new GetImages(getString(R.string.link), i + ".jpg").execute();
    }
}
```

And for some reason it won't download anything, not even the first one.
Someone know how to solve this?
Thanks for the help and your time.

Comment: Is that method being called in first called? Also, try executing `AsyncTask` in parallel via `GetImages("your link").executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried `new GetImages(getString(R.string.link), i + ".jpg").executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);` but it doenst work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because all your `AsyncTasks` will go in same `queue` waiting for each other to be executed. To bypass that you could use `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` but if you take a look into documentation it is not recommended to do that:

> Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a
>   single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel
>   execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, java.lang.Object[])
>   with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

But instead of creating so many instances of `AsyncTask` in loop which can be memory consuming and it is really bad approach, refactor your code.

Pass the `List` of images `urls` to `AsyncTask` and run the `for` loop inside `doInBackground` method. Inside `doInBackground` method download images from `urls` store in `List` of `Bitmaps` and pass to `onPostExecute` once download is finished.

Here you can find working example:
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/02/android-asynctask-download-multiple.html